# how to rename headline text from anywhere under the current header

Tags: org-mode

As I type content under the current header, I often realize that I would like to rename the header --- give it a title more fitting to what I have written. One option is to get up to the header (outline-up-heading), delete the headline text and replace. For obvious reasons, it is often desirable not to leave where I am writing. I'd like to develop a function that will query for a new title in the mode line, and upon entering new title, the headline text is renamed. Is there such a function? If not, any helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there exists such function

```
M-x org-edit-headline
```

The doc string of the function says:

> org-edit-headline is an interactive Lisp closure in ‘org.el’.
>
> (org-edit-headline &optional HEADING)
>
> Edit the current headline.
> Set it to HEADING when provided.

Comment: thanks very much!